# Is there a webpack configuration in which file naming is incremental instead of using an hash function?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I generated a web app with create-react-app and after the build the result is something like:

```
build\static\js\main.52990f3a.js
build\static\css\main.eeea279c.css
```

If I made some changes and run the build again I usually get a result similar but with a different hash.

Is it possible to change this naming system with an incremental one? 
For example:

```
build\static\js\main.v1.js
build\static\css\main.v1.css
```

after some changes and building again:

```
build\static\js\main.v2.js
build\static\css\main.v2.css
```

Thanks